# checking the length of string in mongoldb

Tags: mongodb, string-length

I'm. trying to find the length of a string in MongoDB if anyone can help in aggregate more if possible.
I have tried `$size` but it's for string and `$ifnull` does not work because it's just an empty string.
TKSS

Answer (score 0):

$size is used to check the size of an array. You can always refer mongo documentation.

You can use `strlencp`

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/)

```
  [
    {
      $project: {
        name:1
        "length": { $strLenCP: "$name" }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```